# Disqus plugin not showing on all the posts

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, disqus

I have been trying for a few days to figure this out but to no avail. Actually in my Wordpress blog, I am using the `disqus` plugin for comments but it's only showing 1 or 2 posts of around 15 posts. I can't figure out why it's not coming on all the posts.

I also tried disabling all the remaining plugins except disqus, but that didn't work either.

Also when I compared the page source of the pages in which disqus plugin is coming properly with others that are not showing the disqus plugin, there is no difference as I can see disqus plugin script are coming in both the pages and are same.

Comment: It is showing in one post, two posts or 'one or 2 posts'. please to precise, because the 3 things are different.

Comment: I had something similar for posts that included videos or certain other formatting things in each post, can you find a common denominator for what may be on each of the pages where the disqus comments dont come out?

Comment: Sorry to say but there is hardly any common denominator as my all posts have featured images and text, but one thing that i noticed is that disqus is not coming on my earlier posts but when i am adding a new posts it is coming properly... dont know whats the problem with earlier posts. @ whiteletters and blankspaces : To be precise disqus  is coming in 3 posts out of 8. any help would be great as really want to know root cause of this problem thanks